# Test-Kitchen serverspec testing exception on windows

Tags: windows, chef-infra, test-kitchen, serverspec

When using `chef generate cookbook hello` command, the serverspec `spec_helper.rb` file generated will not work with Test-Kitchen 1.4.1 and windows.

`kitchen verify` command will throw the following on windows platform:

```
C:/Users/vagrant/AppData/Local/Temp/verifier/gems/gems/specinfra-2.37.5/lib/specinfra/backend/exec.rb:98:in `spawn': No such file or directory - /bin/sh -c ls\ /etc/arch-release (Errno::ENOENT)
    from C:/Users/vagrant/AppData/Local/Temp/verifier/gems/gems/specinfra-2.37.5/lib/specinfra/backend/exec.rb:98:in `spawn_command'
    from C:/Users/vagrant/AppData/Local/Temp/verifier/gems/gems/specinfra-2.37.5/lib/specinfra/backend/exec.rb:13:in `block in run_command'
    from C:/Users/vagrant/AppData/Local/Temp/verifier/gems/gems/specinfra-2.37.5/lib/specinfra/backend/exec.rb:133:in `with_env'
    from C:/Users/vagrant/AppData/Local/Temp/verifier/gems/gems/specinfra-2.37.5/lib/specinfra/backend/exec.rb:12:in `run_command'
    from C:/Users/vagrant/AppData/Local/Temp/verifier/gems/gems/specinfra-2.37.5/lib/specinfra/helper/detect_os.rb:13:in `run_command'
    from C:/Users/vagrant/AppData/Local/Temp/verifier/gems/gems/specinfra-2.37.5/lib/specinfra/helper/detect_os/arch.rb:3:in `detect'
    from C:/Users/vagrant/AppData/Local/Temp/verifier/gems/gems/specinfra-2.37.5/lib/specinfra/helper/detect_os.rb:5:in `detect'
    from C:/Users/vagrant/AppData/Local/Temp/verifier/gems/gems/specinfra-2.37.5/lib/specinfra/helper/os.rb:24:in `block in detect_os'
    from C:/Users/vagrant/AppData/Local/Temp/verifier/gems/gems/specinfra-2.37.5/lib/specinfra/helper/os.rb:23:in `each'
    from C:/Users/vagrant/AppData/Local/Temp/verifier/gems/gems/specinfra-2.37.5/lib/specinfra/helper/os.rb:23:in `detect_os'
    from C:/Users/vagrant/AppData/Local/Temp/verifier/gems/gems/specinfra-2.37.5/lib/specinfra/helper/os.rb:9:in `os'
    from C:/Users/vagrant/AppData/Local/Temp/verifier/suites/serverspec/windows_spec.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the test-kitchen `spec_helper.rb` file to test for windows and setting the backend and os accordingly, fixes the issue:

```
require 'serverspec'

if (/cygwin|mswin|mingw|bccwin|wince|emx/ =~ RUBY_PLATFORM).nil?
  set :backend, :exec
else
  set :backend, :cmd
  set :os, family: 'windows'
end
```

You can then test against different platforms, for example:

```
require 'spec_helper'

case os[:family]
when 'windows'
  describe file('C:\Users\vagrant\foo.txt') do
    it { should be_file }
  end
when 'darwin' # mac os x
  describe file('/user/vagrant/foo.txt') do
    it { should be_file }
  end
when 'ubuntu'
  describe file('/home/vagrant/foo.txt') do
    it { should be_file }
  end
end
```